# Accessing the bins intervals with value_count(bins=x)

Tags: python, pandas, bins

I need help with accessing the bins the value_count() function creates.

Tried accessing with print, loops but I don't get how it works.

```py
import pandas as pd
sr = pd.Series(data = [1,2,3,3,4,5,7,1,2])
sr.value_counts(bins=2)
```

the actual output is:

```py
(0.993, 4.0]    7
(4.0, 7.0]      2
```

Comment: In this case, you need `2`?

Comment: What do you mean? I need to know if there is a way to save those intervals in some variable or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get index of `Series`:

```
sr = pd.Series(data = [1,2,3,3,4,5,7,1,2])
s = sr.value_counts(bins=2)
print (s)
(0.993, 4.0]    7
(4.0, 7.0]      2
dtype: int64

print (s.index)
IntervalIndex([(0.993, 4.0], (4.0, 7.0]],
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[float64]')
```

And then select by indexing - e.g. first value:

```
print (s.index[0])
(0.993, 4.0]
```

If need select values in first value of index here is necessary use [`Interval.left`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.left.html) and [`Interval.right`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.right.html), because working with [`Interval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) and select by indexing not working:

```
print (s.index[0].left)
0.993

print (s.index[0].right)
4.0

print (s.index[0][0])
```

> TypeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object does not support indexing